# How do i arrange the widget Icon into right side always

Tags: flutter

Hello I am new on flutter and I am currently working on a design which I saw but the problem is that I am having issue on putting the Icon on the right side and the Row is not same size as others. I hope you can help me so it will broaden my knowledge on this flutter. I just started Flutter this week.

Design intended :

[image]

Current work :

[image]

Code :

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    Widget titleText = Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Select Screen Lock',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
        )
    );

    Widget subTitleText = Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Secure your phone with a screen lock style,',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),),
      ),
    );

    Widget selectionContainer = Container(
      width: 200,
      child: IntrinsicWidth(
        child:  Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _selectMenu('Password'),
            _selectMenu('Pin Code'),
            _selectMenu('Finger Print')
          ],
        ),
      )
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            titleText,
            subTitleText,
            Center(
              child:
              selectionContainer,
            )
          ],
        ),
          ),
        );
      }



 Column _selectMenu(String title){
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(title), Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
              color: Colors.grey,
              size: 16,
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here:

```
Column _selectMenu(String title){
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(title), Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
              color: Colors.grey,
              size: 16,
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
```

First of all, remove Column(why we need it here?), and add space between items(please check `mainAxisAlignment` and `crossAxisAlignment`), then we get

```
Widget _selectMenu(String title){
    return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(title), Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
              color: Colors.grey,
              size: 16,
            )
          ]);
```

Comment: Thank you sir got it.
Actually I am new so i was just following some instruction from previous tutorials and studying it to broaden my knowledge

Comment: no problem, please check, if everything is fine, you feel free to mark this as answer